# Build a mobile website without touching the original website

Tags: php, mobile

We just got a idea to show the power of mobile web to clients. So we were thinking to show clients website in mobile. So its obvious that we wont get access to client code or website. The client website is in PHP. So is there any external tool or application that we can use to configure the website on mobile, with out getting the actual code. Like we have [Kurogo](http://kurogo.org/home/) . But i found that the amount of effort needed in configuring it for a website is too much. So is there any simple tool which we can use. It should just handle images, links and basic content. Just take it and display properly in mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All requests made to example.com should be redirected to m.example.com and in m you provide the necessary web interface for mobile devices.

[JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is very useful tool for building websites design for mobile.